# Using a reactive expression in an if statement in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a shiny app where the output should depend on the value of a variable which is calculated in a reactive expression in shiny. Instead of reproducing the actual app I believe I have recreated my problem with the following simple app:

```
ui.R file:

   library(shiny)

   shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

   headerPanel("Illustrating problem"),

   sidebarPanel(

   numericInput('id1', 'Numeric input, labeled id1', 0, min = 0, max = 100, step        =5)

  ),

  mainPanel(

    h4('You entered'),

    verbatimTextOutput("oid1"),

    verbatimTextOutput("odic")

  )
))

server.R file


library(shiny)

shinyServer(

  function(input, output) {

    output$oid1 <- renderPrint({input$id1})

    x<-reactive({5*input$id1})

    if (x()>50) output$oid2<-renderPrint({"You entered a number greater than 10"})

    else output$oid2<-renderPrint({"You entered a number less than or equal to 
10"})

  }
)
```

If I run it like this then I get the error:
**Error in** `.getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext()` :`

> Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried
>   to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive
>   expression or observer.)

If I change the if statement to: `if (x>50)` ... then I get the error:

> *Error in x > 50 :    comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types*

When I change the if statement to: `if (reactive({(x>50)}))` ... then I get the error message:

> *Error in if (reactive({ : argument is not interpretable as logical*

I'd greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 13):

A couple problems. The first and biggest problem is that you don't seem to understand how reactivity works. The error says "operation not allowed without an active reactive context" and that's the problem - you're accessing `x()` inside the server function's main body but not within a reactive context. Any `render*` function is a reactive context for example.  So to solve this you simple have to move the if statement inside the `renderPrint`.

The other small problem is that your output ids don't match (`verbatimTextOutput("odic")` vs `output$oid2`).

If you don't understand reactivity, I highly suggest you take half an hour to understand it better. [This tutorial](http://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/#reactivity-101) has a section on reactivity that can be helpful, or you can re-read the official shiny tutorial by RStudio.

Here's the code for your fixed app (I removed a bunch of useless UI elements)

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput('id1', 'Numeric input, labeled id1', 0, min = 0, max = 100, step=5),
  verbatimTextOutput("oid1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("oid2")

)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$oid1 <- renderPrint({input$id1})

  x<-reactive({5*input$id1})

  output$oid2<-renderPrint({
    if (x()>50) {
      "You entered a number greater than 10"
    } else {
      "You entered a number less than or equal to 10"
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that Shiny works based according to an event driven model - as do pretty much all graphically oriented UIs (and today that is the vast majority). It is not a new concept, has been around since the 80s at least, but it is more complicated than a programming something that follows a single flowchart  - it does take some getting used to.

Anyway, in Shiny `reactive` and `output` and`observe` statements have to be at the top level, I don't think there are exceptions to this.

You probably want something like this:

```
library(shiny)

u <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Illustrating problem"),

  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput('id1', 'Numeric input, labeled id1', 0, min = 0, max = 100, step =5)
  ),

  mainPanel(

    h4('You entered'),
    verbatimTextOutput("oid1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("oid2")

  )
))

s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$oid1 <- renderPrint({input$id1})

    x<-reactive({5*input$id1})

    output$oid2<-renderPrint({
      if (x()>50){
         "You entered a number greater than 10"
      } else {
         "You entered a number less than or equal to 10"
      }
    }
  )
}
)
shinyApp(ui = u, server = s)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: You get a point too , for the effort of screenshots... BTW I don't think it's encouraged, but you can certainly put output statements inside an observer/reactive. But shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. My problem is that in my actual app I have a whole bunch of commands inside the if else statements, and it is not just a single renderPrint command. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: It is not useful for me either, imagine you want to define a reactive variable only if another reactive variable has a particular value, then you can not use a render environment and must do the if in the main server body

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710358/how-to-create-if-statement-with-reactive-values-in-r-shiny?rq=1. This is one answers my question