# How to create IF statement with reactive values in R ( Shiny )

Tags: r, shiny

Beginner to R and shiny here!
Tried to make a minimal working example... I want to check a condition on a reactive input value. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(

  numericInput(inputId="a", label=NULL, value=0),
  textOutput(outputId="out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- reactive(input$a)
  if (x() < 4) 
    {y<-1}
  else
  {y<-0}

  output$out <- renderText({y})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The error message:

> Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried
>   to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive
>   expression or observer.)

Comment: As the message says, you can only use `x()` within a reactive context (for example, inside `observe`, `local`, `render....` functions). Also you `y` value must be defined outside the `function` and in the same level or upper level of where it is used.

Comment: @warmoverflow : So there is no way to check a condition on a reactive value? Sorry super new to R

Comment: You can but must be inside one of those context. For example you  can check it right inside `renderText`

Comment: BTW `input$a` is already reactive by itself so you don't need to enclose it with `reactive` and assign to a new variable.

Comment: @warmoverflow : I see. That's unfortunate. This was a minimal working example for trying to do a large amount of computation outside of renderOutputs, because my real code is (1) much longer, and (2) has multiple outputs based on y, and recomputing it inside each renderOutput is really slow. Thank you

Comment: I think you do need the `reactive` when you assign the `x` as `input$a` is reactive, but `x` isn't yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer above from John Paul is certainly acceptable, but I thought you might like to see another way as a part of your learning process.  I will let StackOverflow sort out which is more advisable.

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(

  numericInput(inputId="a", label=NULL, value=0),
  textOutput(outputId="out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  state <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    state$x <- input$a
    state$y <- ifelse(state$x < 4, 1, 0)
  })

  output$out <- renderText({ state$y })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a reason why using the `reactiveValues` would be preferable here? I get the impression that the RStudio folks like this better but I don't fully understand what the advantage might be.

Comment: I watched the videos from the conference, and I adopted the approach, but unfortunately don't know why.  I'm about to really dig into the shiny internals, so maybe then I will figure it out.  In terms of a big complicated project, I think the `reactiveValues` approach simplifies some of the code.  I am hoping others on StackOverflow will enlighten us.

Comment: @timelyportfolio Oh I like this! I'll have to play around with reactiveValues() and Observe() but it seems much easier, not having to keep track of which values are reactive, and making sure all downstream variables are assigned with reactive()

Answer (score 12):

You just need to use `reactive` with your `if` so that shiny knows that `y` changes when `x` does.

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(

  numericInput(inputId="a", label=NULL, value=0),
  textOutput(outputId="out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- reactive(input$a)
  y <- reactive( if (x()<4) 1 else 0 )

  output$out <- renderText({ y() })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ah wow great! Assigning the entire IF statement to a variable is not intuitive to me, but you were right.

Answer (score 4):

here's my attempt. 
1) as stated, you don't need to wrap input$a in reactive context and save as x.  just use input$a
2) you don't need reactiveValues in this simple example.  just save y as a reactive variable.  then, in the renderText, access by calling the function ("y()")

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(

  numericInput(inputId="a", label=NULL, value=0),
  textOutput(outputId="out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  y <- reactive({
    if (input$a < 4) {
      return(1)
    } else {
      return(0)
    }
  }
  )

  output$out <- renderText({y()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```